# Flutter app getting installed on Android TV but not opening, why?

Tags: flutter, android-tv

My flutter application is running on an **Android TV emulator** in **Android Studio**, but it's not working on an actual **Android TV** (4.4.4).

minSdk version seems to be 16 in my flutter app. App gets installed in **Android TV** with no errors or any issues, but when try to open it nothing happens. Any help?

I don't know what else I should provide for more clarification, let me know if anything more needed like my whole code.

Answer (score 0):

My issue resolved by making a release version with certificate added into app. The compiler build app version won't work with actual tv with my experience.

*I didn't had a android tv with myself, so needed to goto a shop frequently for checking  my app.*

Comment: Can you explain steps of install certificate. Because I am not able to install release apk in android tv emulator giving me error 
`adb: failed to install app-release.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]`